# table* positioning

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

[image: table]
I am trying to make my table look like this. I have used `table*` environment without `\centering` but the table is centered on the page. Also, is there any way to display the caption like this, beside the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Using [sidecap](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidecap)**

You get caption beside by loading the package [sidecap](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidecap) in your preamble, and use

```
\begin{SCtable*} 

\end{SCtable*}
```

Here is some code. If you prefer the caption to the left, [sidecap](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidecap) has optional arguments that cover for that, also taking care of inner and outer margins, if you have two side documents.

Use the package [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) to format the captions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, fontsize=11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern, lipsum}
\usepackage[ragged]{sidecap}

\usepackage{caption, array}      % Load package caption for decent formatting and spacing
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}  % Use booktabs rules, ragged2e to have ragged text with hyphenation

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\captionsetup[table]{font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{SCtable*}[1][!bh]
\small
\caption{Summary of considered rapidity windows in analysis of $\overline{B}/B$ ratios. The beam energy $\sqrt{^{S}NN}$ is given in $GeV$%
    \label{tab:test123}}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}*{7}{L}}
    \toprule
    \sqrt{^{S}NN} & 200    & 62.4   & 39          & 27         & 19.6      & 11.5 \\
     \midrule
     \Lambda & |y|<1      & |y|<1 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5  \\
     \Theta    & |y|<0.75 & |y|<1 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5  \\
     \Omega  & |y|<1      & |y|<1 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{SCtable*}

\lipsum[5-12]
\end{document}
```

**2. Using [KOMA-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)**

The [KOMA-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes have extensive support for tailoring captions. Here is you table using [scrartcl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl). Alternatively, you may load the package [scrextend](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend), if you prefer using another document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass[captions=topbeside, twocolumn]{scrarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{array}                 % Load package caption for decent formatting and spacing
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}    % Use booktabs rules, ragged2e to have ragged text with hyphenation

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\setcapindent{0pt}
\setcaptionalignment{L}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{table*}
\begin{captionbeside}[Summary]{Summary of considered rapidity windows in analysis of $\overline{B}/B$ ratios. The beam energy $\sqrt{^{S}NN}$ is given in $GeV$ %
    \label{tab:test123}}[o]
\raisebox{0.6\baselineskip}{%
\small
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}*{7}{L}@{}}
  \toprule
  \sqrt{^{S}NN} & 200      & 62.4  & 39      & 27      & 19.6    & 11.5   \\
  \midrule
  \Lambda       & |y|<1    & |y|<1 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5\\
  \Theta        & |y|<0.75 & |y|<1 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5\\
  \Omega        & |y|<1    & |y|<1 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5 & |y|<0.5\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}

\end{captionbeside}
\end{table*}

\lipsum[5-17]
\end{document}
```